# How to convert a column of a table into a tuple?

Tags: sql-update, dolphindb, function-templates, accumulate

Here is a table and I want to update the column with the following script.

```
init=array(DOUBLE, 0) val
t=table(1..5 as id, `a`a`b`b`c as sym, 2022.01.01 + 1..5 as date, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0] as val)
update t set v=accumulate(def(a, b){c=a;c.append!(b);return c}, val, init)
```

The `accumulate` function in this script does not process columns directly because they are vectors. So is there any way to convert a column into a tuple and pass them to the `accumulate` function?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Use `loop` and `asis`. The `update` statement can be rewritten as follows:

```
update t set v = accumulate(def(a, b){c=a;c.append!(b);return c}, loop(asis, val), init)
```

Method 2: Use `cast` directly. The `update` statement can be rewritten as follows:

```
update t set v = accumulate(def(a, b){c=a;c.append!(b);return c}, val$ANY, init)
```

The val column of the new t table is of ANY type.

Note: `cast` is more efficient than `loop` and `asis` for the conversion. And `cast` is 50% faster than `loop` and `asis`.

This method works for versions prior to 1.30.21/2.00.9. Starting from 1.30.21/2.00.9, the higher-order functions have been enhanced. You can directly run the script in your question.